# load all the MYSQL tables into data frames with same names

Tags: r, rmysql

I have successfully loaded all MySQL tables into as many dataframe variables, all of same names as table names (this was a personal learning) using the following code. My question is: Is there a better method, as I get a feeling this is quite slow.

```
db<-dbConnect(MySQL(),user='****',password="****",dbname="****",host='XX.XXX.XXX.XX') 

  tables<-dbListTables(db)

  #load all tables in variables with same name as the MySQL table name. 
  #warning : this loop will take more than 90 seconds to complete and will download all the MySQL tables.
  for (i in 1:NROW(tables)){
    assign(tables[i],dbReadTable(db,tables[i]))
  }

#release the DB
  dbDisconnect(db)
```

Is this the fastest method on the planet?

Comment: The limiting factor here in terms of speed will not be the R code, but your connection to the db and the size of the tables. However, a better approach would be to put all the data frames in a named list (use `lapply` over the table names) and if you're just learning R, forget you ever heard of `assign`; don't use it.

Comment: `dfList <- lapply(tables, function(t) dbReadTable(db, t))`

Comment: @Parfait: this will store the tables in an array (list). But I need them in variable names that are the same as the tables in the DB.

Comment: @joran: If I do not use _assign_ what is the alternative to store something in variables that have names embedded in an array _tables_ as above?

Comment: A named list is functionally equivalent to what you describe, and actually better. Having lots of individual variables in your global namespace makes them all much harder to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown, consider saving all MySQL tables into **one** list of many dataframes which avoids having to manage many objects in your global environment. Below even names the list elements to the corresponding table name which can be referenced with `$` or `[[..]]` indexing:

```
# DATA FRAME LIST OF NAMED ELEMENTS
dfList <- setNames(lapply(tables, function(t) dbReadTable(db, t)), tables)

dfList$table1Name    
dfList[["table2Name"]]    
...
```

Hence, you can access each dataframe by index and run any dataframe operations as if they were independent objects:

```
aggregate(.~Group1 + Group2, dfList$table1Name, FUN=sum)

merge(dfList$table1Name, dfList$table2Name, by="joinkey")

by(dfList$table1Name, dfList$table1Name[c("factor1", "factor2")], FUN=summary)
```

Now, if you really, really do want multiple variables, use `list2env` to output list elements to separate objects:

```
list2env(dfList, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: +1 for the named list creation idea @Parfait
But I have a small concern:
The mem utilisation (measured through Object Size) is almost double in the list style. I measured for just one table. 
`object.size(dfList$table1)` is twice as much than 
`object.size(table1)` where table1 is a transformed dataframe with one extra column from the source data dfList$table1. So despite an extra variable added we have a reduction of 50%. Why?

Comment: I did some investigations and found it is not the list but the date char string that when converted to POSIXlt form Date shrinks the size. That makes sense.

Comment: So, did this answer your question? Also, here you are attempting to store all your MySQL database (stored on server hard disk) inside an R memory environment. Consider working on a table one at a time if resources are limited.

Comment: Yes, the question is answered quite well @Parfait. And yes I agree the memory requirements will grow as the DB increases and then one table at a time will be better. Right now I have less than 60 MB (object_size) for all the 60 tables together. So this is manageable.